# How to parse simple list of identifier in function-like proc macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'd like to build a function-like proc_macro that accepts a list of type names, and then does some stuff with them. I don't need any fancy syntax, I just want something like

```
my_macro!(foo::Bar, baz::Quuz, A, B);
```

and I might want to, e.g. generate a global of each type, like

```
static global0: foo::Bar = Default::default();
static global1: baz::Quux = Default::default();
...
```

What's the most straightforward way to parse this? I've had some success with the `syn` crate for parsing well-formed rust code, and it has [docs on parsing custom syntax](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/#parsing-a-custom-syntax), but that seems like it might be overkill for such a simple case.

Comment: Do you need a _path_, or a _type_? A type can include things like `(A, B)` (tuple) or `<A as B>::C`.

Comment: @cafce25 It's not possible to programmatically generate variable names in declarative macros. The names `global0`, `global1` etc would need to be passed into the macro in order to use them as the names of new variables.

Comment: @SvenMarnach this is not quite true. Hygiene prevents you from leaking identifiers that are created locally, but that does not apply to items so it's ok for statics. Besides, you cannot *directly* create new identifiers programmatically, but nothing prevents you from using a proc-macro library (such as [paste](https://github.com/dtolnay/paste) that does specifically that, and write everything else as a declarative macro.

Comment: @jthulhu The problem is that it's impossible to call that proc macro in the position of the newly defined identifier. You'd have to move the whole item into the proc macro, at which point all the declarative macro is doing is calling the proc macro repeatedly.

Comment: @SvenMarnach indeed, that's exactly how `paste` is intended to be used. And it's much more convenient than writing a proc macro yourself, if only because you don't have to create a new crate just for that.

Comment: @jthulhu Yeah, sorry, my comments were kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`syn` is the way to go. However, you don't need to go for custom syntax - `syn` has [`Punctuated`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/punctuated/struct.Punctuated.html) to handle this case.

```rust
use syn::parse::Parser;
let data = syn::punctuated::Punctuated::<syn::Type, syn::Token![,]>::parse_terminated
    .parse2(tokens)
    .unwrap();
```